# By selecting sex cells after meiosis, would it be possible to create two offspring with inverse parental DNA of one another?

Tags: dna, meiosis

Would it theoretically be possible to select two sex cells after a male meiosis (filtering out the two where crossover had taken place) and combine each with two sex from a female meiosis (imagining they were all egg cells, even though only one would be) to create offspring with inverse inherited parental DNA of one another?

For example: If the mother's DNA is AB and father's is CD then the offspring could have AC and BD - inherited from both parents but completely different from one another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Theoretically?** Yes. Very theoretically possible.

**In practice?** It's difficult to isolate the exact daughter cells (sperm) from the same meiotic event, have these cells complete maturation, and only then have them fertilize an egg. Normally you need quite a lot of sperm cells even with *in vitro* fertilization, but also in principle all you need would be a single sperm cell to make a zygote!

**To address some misconception:** when you say "inherited from both parents *but completely different*", that applies also for regular sex cells and fertilized eggs. You don't need to fish for the precise 2 daughter cells following meiosis to get this outcome. Mitosis produces 2 genetic copies, while meiosis in humans produces *4 unique daughter cells*. All individuals, as diploid as we are as humans, are products of genomes that have been very well shuffled (recombined).

**Reality:** the real-life reasons to perform such a procedure would be taken as very dubious, so I don't think realistically anyone would perform this. But in the designer baby era of the future, who knows!

Comment: Sure it would be bery dubious. Was just a silly idea i had. I did have a misconception about crossover where i thought only 2 daughter cells would recombine, when it seems they all do. Still, it seems the resulting children would have mutually exclusive DNA besides that which is shared by both parents. Would i be right in thinking that one child would recive an X chromosome and the other Y from the sperm making the children opposite sex too?

Comment: Correct! The ratio of Y and X chromosomes in the haploid sex cells (spermatozoa) is 50:50 as a result of meiotic distribution, and this originates from the X and Y chromosomes being separated between two daughter cells during meiosis.

Answer (score 2):

### Here there be monsters

The biggest problem with your scenario as presented is that the complementary genes in the female do not go into the *"secondary oocyte"* but into the *"first polar body"* ("2" below).

[image]

The first polar body remains in the perivitelline space beside the oocyte, but it is a tiny thing, generally considered too small to potentially make a zygote.  It is emitted as a diploid during the first division of meiosis, and divides again afterward.  I think the one below has already divided.

Now, because it's impossible, we should naturally expect to find such a case, and I will not disappoint:  [Bieber, 1981](https://science.sciencemag.org/content/213/4509/775).  In that case the polar body had not divided yet, and the resulting twin, within the chorion, was a triploid and severely deformed "acardiac monster".  A [2015 review](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/26548710/) mentions polar body twinning without describing the possibility of diploids, so I'll assume this hasn't actually been demonstrated.  I know the first polar body is a bit half-hearted about its division.

[image]

It should be relatively straightforward to obtain immature sperm while they are still linked by cytoplasmic bridges as illustrated above, do [in vitro sperm maturation](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/10645263/) to obtain complementary sperm, and attempt some sort of fertilization of egg and a daughter of the first polar body.  The resulting twins would share a chorion but monochorionic and diamniotic.  Such a procedure would still be very likely to produce a malformed embryo due to the development of a very tiny zygote.  I was concerned about epigenetic differences, but after a helpful comment, I did find a reference that [the methylome is similar to that of the secondary oocyte](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/33313772/), and [a paper reporting that it is possible to transfer polar body nuclei to oocytes with 42% viability](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5218919/).  Given remaining uncertainty and a lack of apparent medical necessity, it might still be more advisable to stick to [routine human cloning with germline genetic modification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/He_Jiankui). :)

Comment: I knew there'd be a problem with female meiosis producing only one egg, but I guessed maybe DNA could maybe be transplanted from a polar body into another egg. I hadn't considered that epigenetic information could make this infeasible, so thanks for the additional information.

Comment: You are right!  I'd seen one thing about epigenetic changes and polar body extrusion which I may have misinterpreted, given other sources I found.  I'll update the answer accordingly.